# numpy reshaping multdimensional array through arbitrary axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

so this is a question regarding the **use of reshape and how this functions uses each axis on a multidimensional scale**.

Suppose I have the following array that contains matrices indexed by the first index. **What I want to achieve is to instead index the columns of each matrix with the first index**. In order to illustrate this problem, consider the following example where the given numpy array that indexes matrices with its first index is z.

```
x = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
y = np.arange(9, 18).reshape((3, 3))
z = np.dstack((x, y)).T
```

Where z looks like:

```
array([[[ 0,  3,  6],
    [ 1,  4,  7],
    [ 2,  5,  8]],

   [[ 9, 12, 15],
    [10, 13, 16],
    [11, 14, 17]]])
```

And its shape is `(2, 3, 3)`. Here, the first index are the two images and the three x three is a matrix.

The question more specifically phrased then, is how to use reshape to obtain the following **desired output**:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
   [ 3,  4,  5],
   [ 6,  7,  8],
   [ 9, 10, 11],
   [12, 13, 14],
   [15, 16, 17]])
```

Whose shape is `(6, 3)`. This achieves that the dimension of the array indexes the columns of the matrix x and y as presented above. My natural *inclination was to use reshape directly on z* in the following way:

```
out = z.reshape(2 * 3, 3)
```

But its output is the following which indexes the rows of the matrices and not the columns:

```
array([[ 0,  3,  6],
   [ 1,  4,  7],
   [ 2,  5,  8],
   [ 9, 12, 15],
   [10, 13, 16],
   [11, 14, 17]]
```

Could reshape be used to obtain the desired output above? Or **more general, can you control how each axis is used when you use the reshape function**?

Two things:

- I know how to solve the problem. I can go through each element of the big matrix (z) transposed and then apply reshape in the way above. This increases computation time a little bit and is not really problematic. But it does not generalize and it does not feel python. So I was wondering if there is a standard enlightened way of doing this.
- I was not clear on how to phrase this question. If anyone has suggestion on how to better phrase this problem I am all ears.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Every array has a natural (1D flattened) order to its elements. When you reshape an array, it is *as though* it were flattened first (thus obtaining the natural order), and then reshaped:

```
In [54]: z.ravel()
Out[54]: 
array([ 0,  3,  6,  1,  4,  7,  2,  5,  8,  9, 12, 15, 10, 13, 16, 11, 14,
       17])

In [55]: z.ravel().reshape(2*3, 3)
Out[55]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6],
       [ 1,  4,  7],
       [ 2,  5,  8],
       [ 9, 12, 15],
       [10, 13, 16],
       [11, 14, 17]])
```

Notice that in the "natural order", 0 and 1 are far apart. However you reshape it, 0 and 1 will not be next to each other along the last axis, which is what you want in the desired array:

```
desired = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],
                    [ 3,  4,  5],
                    [ 6,  7,  8],
                    [ 9, 10, 11],
                    [12, 13, 14],
                    [15, 16, 17]])
```

This requires some reordering, which in this case can be done by `swapaxes`:

```
In [53]: z.swapaxes(1,2).reshape(2*3, 3)
Out[53]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17]])
```

because `swapaxes(1,2)` places the values in the desired order

```
In [56]: z.swapaxes(1,2).ravel()
Out[56]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17])

In [57]: desired.ravel()
Out[57]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17])
```

Note that the `reshape` method also has a `order` parameter which can be used to control the (C- or F-) order with which the elements are read from the array and placed in the reshaped array. However, I don't think this helps in your case.

---

Another way to think about the limits of `reshape` is to say that all reshapes followed by ravel are the same:

```
In [71]: z.reshape(3,3,2).ravel()
Out[71]: 
array([ 0,  3,  6,  1,  4,  7,  2,  5,  8,  9, 12, 15, 10, 13, 16, 11, 14,
       17])

In [72]: z.reshape(3,2,3).ravel()
Out[72]: 
array([ 0,  3,  6,  1,  4,  7,  2,  5,  8,  9, 12, 15, 10, 13, 16, 11, 14,
       17])

In [73]: z.reshape(3*2,3).ravel()
Out[73]: 
array([ 0,  3,  6,  1,  4,  7,  2,  5,  8,  9, 12, 15, 10, 13, 16, 11, 14,
       17])

In [74]: z.reshape(3*3,2).ravel()
Out[74]: 
array([ 0,  3,  6,  1,  4,  7,  2,  5,  8,  9, 12, 15, 10, 13, 16, 11, 14,
       17])
```

So if the ravel of the desired array is different, there is no way to obtain it only be reshaping.

---

The same goes for reshaping with `order='F'`, provided you also ravel with `order='F'`:

```
In [109]: z.reshape(2,3,3, order='F').ravel(order='F')
Out[109]: 
array([ 0,  9,  1, 10,  2, 11,  3, 12,  4, 13,  5, 14,  6, 15,  7, 16,  8,
       17])

In [110]: z.reshape(2*3*3, order='F').ravel(order='F')
Out[110]: 
array([ 0,  9,  1, 10,  2, 11,  3, 12,  4, 13,  5, 14,  6, 15,  7, 16,  8,
       17])

In [111]: z.reshape(2*3,3, order='F').ravel(order='F')
Out[111]: 
array([ 0,  9,  1, 10,  2, 11,  3, 12,  4, 13,  5, 14,  6, 15,  7, 16,  8,
       17])
```

---

It is possible to obtain the desired array using two reshapes:

```
In [83]: z.reshape(2, 3*3, order='F').reshape(2*3, 3)
Out[83]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17]])
```

but I stumbled upon this serendipidously.

---

If I've totally misunderstood your question and `x` and `y` are the givens (not `z`) then you could obtain the desired array using `row_stack` instead of `dstack`:

```
In [88]: z = np.row_stack([x, y])

In [89]: z
Out[89]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17]])
```

Comment: Not, you did not misunderstood,  you totally nailed it. x and y where just constructs for the working example. What I care about is a z that is far far bigger along the first axis.

Answer (score 1):

It you look at `dstack` code you'll discover that

```
np.dstack((x, y)).T
```

is effectively:

```
np.concatenate([i[:,:,None] for i in (x,y)],axis=2).transpose([2,1,0])
```

It reshapes each component array and then joins them along this new axis.  Finally it transposes axes.

Your target is the same as (row stack)

```
np.concatenate((x,y),axis=0)
```

So with a bit of reverse engineering we can create it from `z` with

```
np.concatenate([i[...,0] for i in np.split(z.T,2,axis=2)],axis=0)
np.concatenate([i.T[:,:,0] for i in np.split(z,2,axis=0)],axis=0)
```

or

```
np.concatenate(np.split(z.T,2,axis=2),axis=0)[...,0]
```

or with a partial transpose we can keep the split-and-rejoin axis first, and just use `concatenate`:

```
np.concatenate(z.transpose(0,2,1),axis=0)
```

or its reshape equivalent

```
(z.transpose(0,2,1).reshape(-1,3))
```