# More idiomatic way to display images in a grid with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing

Is there a more idiomatic way to display a grid of images as in the below example?

```
import numpy as np

def gallery(array, ncols=3):
    nrows = np.math.ceil(len(array)/float(ncols))
    cell_w = array.shape[2]
    cell_h = array.shape[1]
    channels = array.shape[3]
    result = np.zeros((cell_h*nrows, cell_w*ncols, channels), dtype=array.dtype)
    for i in range(0, nrows):
        for j in range(0, ncols):
            result[i*cell_h:(i+1)*cell_h, j*cell_w:(j+1)*cell_w, :] = array[i*ncols+j]
    return result
```

I tried using `hstack` and `reshape` etc, but could not get the right behaviour.

I am interested in using numpy to do this because there is a limit to how many images you can plot with matplotlib calls to `subplot` and `imshow`.

If you need sample data to test you can use your webcam like so:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
_, img = cv2.VideoCapture(0).read()

plt.imshow(gallery(np.array([img]*6)))
```

Comment: What is the shape of `array`?

Comment: Its 4 dimensions (index, rows, columns, intensity). Where intensity = 3.

Comment: I am not able to run it. Could you post a sample/test it out at your end?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gallery(array, ncols=3):
    nindex, height, width, intensity = array.shape
    nrows = nindex//ncols
    assert nindex == nrows*ncols
    # want result.shape = (height*nrows, width*ncols, intensity)
    result = (array.reshape(nrows, ncols, height, width, intensity)
              .swapaxes(1,2)
              .reshape(height*nrows, width*ncols, intensity))
    return result

def make_array():
    from PIL import Image
    return np.array([np.asarray(Image.open('face.png').convert('RGB'))]*12)

array = make_array()
result = gallery(array)
plt.imshow(result)
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

---

We have an array of shape `(nrows*ncols, height, weight, intensity)`.
We want an array of shape `(height*nrows, width*ncols, intensity)`.

So the idea here is to first use `reshape` to split apart the first axis into two axes, one of length `nrows` and one of length `ncols`:

```
array.reshape(nrows, ncols, height, width, intensity)
```

This allows us to use `swapaxes(1,2)` to reorder the axes so that the shape becomes
`(nrows, height, ncols, weight, intensity)`. Notice that this places `nrows` next to `height` and `ncols` next to `width`.

Since [`reshape` does not change the raveled order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35226493/190597) of the data, `reshape(height*nrows, width*ncols, intensity)` now produces the desired array.

This is (in spirit) the same as the idea used in the [`unblockshaped` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16873755/190597).

Comment: how can I do this if I want to select 16 different images from my saved images in 4*4 array? here you are using the same image

Comment: Question: doesn't the `convert('RGB')` return a 3-channel image? How does this result in a final shape of `(nrows*ncols, height, weight, intensity)`? It somehow seems the 3 channels `R`, `G` and `B` became a single `intensity` channel?

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use [view_as_blocks](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks) .  Then you avoid to swap axes by hand :

```
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks
import numpy as np

def refactor(im_in,ncols=3):
    n,h,w,c = im_in.shape
    dn = (-n)%ncols # trailing images
    im_out = (np.empty((n+dn)*h*w*c,im_in.dtype)
           .reshape(-1,w*ncols,c))
    view=view_as_blocks(im_out,(h,w,c))
    for k,im in enumerate( list(im_in) + dn*[0] ):
        view[k//ncols,k%ncols,0] = im 
    return im_out
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based off @unutbu's, but this deals with `HWC` ordered tensors. Furthermore, it shows black tiles for any channels that do not factorize evenly into the given rows/columns.

```
def tile(arr, nrows, ncols):
    """
    Args:
        arr: HWC format array
        nrows: number of tiled rows
        ncols: number of tiled columns
    """
    h, w, c = arr.shape
    out_height = nrows * h
    out_width = ncols * w
    chw = np.moveaxis(arr, (0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0))

    if c < nrows * ncols:
        chw = chw.reshape(-1).copy()
        chw.resize(nrows * ncols * h * w)

    return (chw
        .reshape(nrows, ncols, h, w)
        .swapaxes(1, 2)
        .reshape(out_height, out_width))
```

Here's a corresponding *detiling* function for the reverse direction:

```
def detile(arr, nrows, ncols, c, h, w):
    """
    Args:
        arr: tiled array
        nrows: number of tiled rows
        ncols: number of tiled columns
        c: channels (number of tiles to keep)
        h: height of tile
        w: width of tile
    """
    chw = (arr
        .reshape(nrows, h, ncols, w)
        .swapaxes(1, 2)
        .reshape(-1)[:c*h*w]
        .reshape(c, h, w))

    return np.moveaxis(chw, (0, 1, 2), (2, 0, 1)).reshape(h, w, c)
```